# Difference between SSL VPN tunneling and SSL in HTTPS

Tags: ssl, vpn, encryption

I'm a beginner, and this is probably an elementary question, but I can't figure it out through some googling.

I'm learning about VPN tunneling right now, and am generally not clear on how VPN tunneling is different than any other encryption, but particularly I am not sure why HTTPS web browsing, which is already using SSL for encryption, would be more secure if it was routed through a VPN using SSL to secure the connection.

What is the added security of a VPN when the communication is already encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

With a TLS/SSL connection to a website, your network provider can't see your traffic but they can see what IP address you’re connecting too, and can make a pretty good guess at the kind of content you’re viewing from the data volumes and the timing of the packets. With a VPN, they get less of that information, because all of your traffic just goes to the VPN (though of course the VPN provider gets the information instead).

Comment: So were one to trust their network provider there is no reason to use VPN?

Comment: No, there are other reasons to use VPNs, but those reasons don’t apply to Internet websites accessed with TLS/SSL, which is what we’re discussing here.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that you won't make HTTPS more secure by tunneling it over a TLS (formerly SSL) VPN, since HTTPS is HTTP already wrapped in TLS.

As Mike said, using a VPN you'll reveal less metadata about your connection, in particular the requested URLs.

Also, if you have a misconfigured site that uses a mix of HTTP and HTTPS, the VPN will protect all of that, reducing your exposure to eavesdropping or man-in-the-middle attacks.